# How to show a UIView inside a UIViewController in ios5?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIView` designed in `XIB` file. Basically with a navigation bar and a button to close the `UIVIew`. I want to show this `UIView` in several `UIViewControllers` across the app.
Below is the code I have imp[emnted so far.**However the `UIView` doesn't show up**.

My `ViewControllers` are designed in `storyboard` however I needed a simple UIView that is why I created a new custom subclass of UIView alongwith a xib file of the same name.The File's Owner is also set to custom subclass. What else is required here?

```
@interface BottomSlidingView : UIView   //this is my UIView
{

}


@implementation BottomSlidingView          

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
   [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   NSLog(@"Bottom View Loaded");   //I get this log entry but the view doesn't showup.

}
    return self;
  }

- (BOOL)loadMyNibFile {
if (![[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BottomSlidingView" owner:self options:nil]) {
    return NO;
}
    return YES;
}
```

And this is how I call the custom `UIView` in my `UIViewController`.

```
 -(void)shareButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
 {
   NSLog(@"share button clicked");
   BottomSlidingView *bsv = [[BottomSlidingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 480, 280, 420)];
   [bsv loadMyNibFile];
   [self.view insertSubview:bsv belowSubview:self.optionsToolBar]; //this toolbar is a subview that I am adding to this view controller.

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple problems with your approach:

1. Create the view instance from a nib file, rather than instantiating it with `initWithFrame:`. For example (if the custom view is the only root-level object in the nib file):

   ```
   + (instancetype)bottomSlidingView
   {
       return [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BottomSlidingView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
   }
   ```
2. Implement [awakeFromNib](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [initWithCoder:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/initWithCoder%3a) instead of `initWithFrame:` (which isn't called when loading from nibs) in your `UIView` subclass.

In your view controller, you would use something like the following to create the view:

```
- (void)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    BottomSlidingView *slidingView = [BottomSlidingView bottomSlidingView];
    [slidingView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 480, 280, 420)];
    [[self view] insertSubview:slidingView belowSubview:[self optionsToolBar]];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to call it from UIViewController if i am using the class method that you have shown above i.e. + (UIView *)bottomSlidingView since i am confused on how to call it on button click action.

Comment: Well i did implement the method in my UIViewController However now i am getting an error that is.....
self BottomSlidingView * 0x00000000
aDecoder NSCoder * 0x0993e400

Comment: To call + (UIView *)bottomSlidingView you should use [BottomSlidingView bottomSlidingView];

Comment: Okay....i made a sample project just to test this. However the same error is occurring.Can anyone throw some light on the issue.The Xcode shows EXC_bad_access error on this line " self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];"

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you want to reuse a UIView of a UIViewController in another view controller you need to use this....

```
YourViewController * child = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];//View controller of view , you want to reuse
[self.view addSubView:child.YourView]; //YourView = Name of view, you want to reuse
[self addChildViewController:child];
[child release];
```

After adding childViewController All IBActions will be work in child.

And after removing this view You have to remove YourViewController from parentViewController other wise there will be memory issues.......

Comment: tell me your confusion. i have created an application of 32 view controllers without using Navigation controller or tabbar controller or story board but only using this concept....

Comment: i have several view controllers designed in storyboard..and there one just plain UIView for which i used .Xib file to design.now for showing this UIView in one of the ViewControllers in storyboard i tried the above code....however now the view doesn't show up.....I can show a UIView by code....but i need to use this several times....thats why i was thinking of using .Xib file....think of it like a custom action sheet view.....with storyboard and .xib combined.

Comment: Sushrut, Sorry i have not tried this code on story board but if you are using XIB then it will work fine.
And if you have only one VIEW to reuse then use Xib and make one mainWindow.xib.
For making mainWindow.xib use [THIS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sROdA4w4x9Y) tutorial.
And then add that view in mainwindow.xib and give outlet in appdelegate.
When you want to use this view write `[appdel.window addSubView:appdel.yourView]` 
Hope this will help you